# iperf connects but does not report output

Tags: iperf, iperf3

I am using iperf to test network bandwidth between two Ubuntu 16.04.2 hosts (10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.51). I ran "iperf -s" on 10.0.0.51 and then ran "iperf -c 10.0.0.51 -T 10" on 10.0.0.1. I do see the connection establishment (i.e. local 10.0.0.51 port 5001 connected with 10.0.0.1 port 37680) on both the sides but I do not get the results. It just hangs. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with iperf3, you can see the output in json format:
The command:

```
iperf3 -c <server-ip> -w 4000 -t 10 -i 2  -f MBytes -V -J --logfile test.log
```

Note: In this case make sure you can run iperf client and server same version i.e version 3 in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Check for firewalls or packet filters, e.g. for linux use iptables -L to list them and iptables -F to delete them all.  Also, what version of iperf?  You might want to display interval reports (-i 1) and see what they are reporting.